# Internal representation of objects

Tags: c++, object, pointers, dereference

So all this time I thought that when you do something like ObjectA.field1, ObjectA is just like any value on the stack and you basically access its fields. Now I was going through the notes for a class about OOP languages and realized that when you do ObjectA.field1 what actually happens is HEAP(Address of ObjectA)(field1) which returns you the value of the field1. This makes me a bit confused. Can anyone tell why there is a look up going on although we already have the value of the object? Hope I was able to explain..

Comment: It's not clear to me what `HEAP` is supposed to do.

Comment: HEAP takes in an address and returns an object

Comment: So HEAP(Address of ObjectA) returns ObjectA. Then what does ObjectA(field1) do?

Comment: Returns the value of the field1

Comment: This `HEAP()` thing doesn't make much sense; I know of no such concept in the C++ language.  Do you have a function or macro by that name defined somewhere?  What does it do?  An object needn't be allocated on the heap; it can be on the stack or in static data (those aren't necessarily language-defined terms).  When you refer to an object by name, the compiler knows how to generate code to access that object in memory.  A field (more precisely, a member) of an object exists somewhere within the memory that the object occupies, at a known offset and with a known size.

Comment: Old but great book about this and lots more: "Inside the C++ Object Model" by Stanley B. Lippman (http://amzn.com/0201834545)

Comment: @Cemre you sound like you're getting confused by the concepts of "ObjectA" and the address of ObjectA in memory (which might be in the heap, or might be on the stack, depending on how you declared your instance named "ObjectA".  Regardless, to get fiel1 from anything, the computer really does have to look someplace in memory.  That's what it means to access field1.  There is no need to worry about the fact that it has an address in memory for most intents & purposes (though you'll be a better programmer if you do learn how it all works under the hood).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Objects aren't really that magical. Essentially, an object just consists of a linear collection of all its members, with unspecified amounts of padding surrounding the members. Layout-wise, a C++ class is essentially like a C struct:

```
struct Foo {
  int a;
  char b;
  std::string s;

  static long q;

  void bar() { print(s); log(a); }
  static void car() { }
}
```

Ignoring member functions and statics for now, this might be laid out like this:

```
+= class Foo =+
+-------------+  ---\   <---   Foo * p
|  int        |     s
+-------------+     i
|  char       |     z
+-------------+     e
| <padding>   |     o
+-------------+     f
| std::string |    (F
+-------------+     o
| <padding>   |     o)
+-------------+  ---/
```

Every object of class `Foo` is stored like this in memory. The only extra data we need are the static members, member functions, and static member functions.

*Static members* are just global variables. So we have only *one* global variable:

```
+== static__Foo__q ==+
+--------------------+
|  long int          |
+--------------------+
```

Next up, *static member functions* are just ordinary, free functions:

```
void static__Foo__car() {  }
```

Finally, *member functions*: these are essentially also just ordinary functions, though with an extra parameter that allows them to find instance members:

```
void member__Foo__bar(Foo * p) { print(p->s); log(p->a); }
```

The only important difference is that you cannot obtain an ordinary free function pointer to member functions, since the actual name of the implementation function is not exposed. The only way to refer to `Foo::bar()` is via a pointer-to-member-function `void (Foo::*ptfm)() = &Foo::bar`. Member objects are a bit simpler: you can either obtain a normal pointer to them, like `Foo x; int * p = &x.a;`, but you can also form a pointer-to-member: `int Foo::*ptm = &Foo::a;`.

Then, if we have objects `Foo x, y, z;`, we can use the *pairs* of instance pointer `Foo * pi = &x;` and member pointers `int &Foo::* ptm = &Foo::a` or `void (Foo::*ptfm)() = &Foo::bar` to access the relevant member of the given instance: the integer `pi->*ptm`, and the function call `(pi->*ptfm)()`, respectively. (Yes, `->*` is an operator.)

(A free version of the function pointer cannot exist, because polymorphic (virtual) functions require a more complicated dispatch mechanism than a simple, fixed function pointer.)

Comment: +1 For the ASCII art.I sure do know it takes a lot of effort :)

Comment: I fixed the last part about member *objects*: You can have both a direct, free pointer to a member object (`&x.a`), and *also* an instance-pointer/member-pointer pair, `(&x, &Foo::a)`.

Comment: Can you also explain why is padding required between `char` and `std::string` objects ?

Comment: @FreakEnum: well, that's just a hypothetical example, but assuming that the alignment of `int` and `std::string` is both 4 (or 8) and that of `char` is 1, you need the padding to obtain the correct alignment.

Answer (score 3):

To get the `field1` of some `ObjectA` of some `ClassA`the computer has to have the address of the memory zone containing `ObjectA`, it knows (statically) the offset (in bytes) for `field1` (of `ClassA`) so it can retrieve the `field1` by adding that offset to the adress of `ObjectA`.

Comment: So, when we dereference a pointer to we get the value of the object or do we get "the real address" of the object ? thanks for the reply

Comment: A pointer is the address of the object. And usually, you dereference it with an offset, as I explained.

Comment: When doing ObjectA.field1 there's no dereferencing of pointers at the level of the C++ language. ObjectA is an lvalue which is comprised of a series of bytes in memory. To access field1, the program has information about which bytes of an object comprise each of its fields. So ObjectA.field1 is an expression that results in an lvalue comprised of the bytes of ObjectA that make up the sub-object field1.