# Pointer-to-member selection

Tags: c++

I have seen the following binary operator listed on a book [pp 191](http://www.apibook.com),

```
Point-to-member selection  x->*y
```

I understand `x->y` but not `x->*y`. Is this a typo or something else?

Comment: Perhaps you'll find [this previous answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8198062/596781) useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something else. See the C++ FAQ here:

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html

Answer (score 6):

### [InformIT: C++ Reference Guide > Pointers to Members](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=142)

---

`y` is a pointer to a member-type inside the type of `*x`, see the example below.

```
struct Obj { int m; };
```

...

```
 Obj        o;  
 Obj *      p = &o; 

 int Obj::* y = &Obj::m;

 // 'y' can point to any int inside Obj, currently it's pointing at Obj::m
 // do notice that it's not bound to any specific instance of Obj

 o.m = 10; 

 std::cout << (p->* y) << std::endl; 
 std::cout << (o .* y) << std::endl;
```

output

```
10
10
```